# Why does the zenburn colour scheme look different on different computers

Tags: themes, colors

I have just started using the zenburn theme in emacs on my macbook and I really like how it looks. It looks like this:

[image: MacbookZenburn]

However when I put it on my ubuntu pc (my .emacs.d directory is synced with git and I double checked it was working properly by copying it over through dropbox as well and the files should be identical in both .emacs.d directories) it looked like this:

[image: UbuntuZenburn]

Can anyone suggest what's going on here and how I can get emacs to look the same on my ubuntu machine as on my macbook?

Comment: It looks like your terminal on Ubuntu is only set up to use 16 colors.  Check out this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64585/1590790

Comment: Are you running emacs inside a terminal? If so, run it outside of a terminal; you'll be happier over all.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, I did M-x list-colors-display in emacs and my macbook terminal has 256 colours while my ubuntu terminal has only 8, that'd explain it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the terminal on my ubuntu computer was only using 8 colours, and as such couldn't use the colours shown on my macbook.

You can find out how many colours your terminal has in emacs using `M-x list-colors-display`

The solution was either to run it outside the terminal or add `[[ $COLORTERM = gnome-terminal ]] && TERM=xterm-256color`(found at stackoverflow.com/a/64585/1590790/) to my .bashrc file so that it could use 256 colours.